# Error term in multiple regression model

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, model, error, r-squared

I am trying to run a multiple regression model to see the effect of field characteristics such as soil texture, slope and hydraulic conductivity on drainage density. 
My samples are agricultural fields on a county so they are divided into 3 main regions. Further, some of the fields are closer to each other.

I would be thankful if you could help me answer following questions.

1. How do i include error term in the model to remove the possible correlation error due to fields that are closer to each other?
2. R-Square value is really small for the regression. Is it affected by the  the possible correlation error due to fields?

I have attached a picture of my sample fields. [image]

Answer (score 1):

1) If you suspect there is strong spatial autocorrelation between the fields (for instance after applying [Moran's I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran%27s_I) test) then a linear mixed effects model would be an appropriate first step. See [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/spatial_regression.htm) for a description how to use the $\mathtt{R}$ $\mathtt{lme}$ package to run a mixed effects model that accounts for spatial autocorrelation.

2) Typically, if there is strong *positive* spatial autocorrelation between sample sites then you would expect to see the reverse - the coefficient of determination (or R-Squared) would be biased *upwards* and standard errors for variable coefficients biased downwards. A low R-Squared may instead indicate important variables are missing from your model.

Comment: Since this is a regression model, applying any test of spatial correlation to the raw response would seem to be uninformative and of little use.  Didn't you intend to indicate that Moran's I should be applied to the *residuals* from some kind of initial regression?

Comment: @whuber - That's correct, the residuals for each field's expected drainage density. The $\mathtt{ape}$ package can be used to calculate Moran's I.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried using the spatial autocorrelation on the residuals in SAS and now I am trying to figure out the autocorrelation using the semivariogram of the residuals.